# Checkbox to Hide/Unhide Row Not Unhiding

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form control checkbox and the following code to hide and unhide row 10.
It hides but does not unhide.

```
Sub CheckBox1_Click()

    If Range("C84").Value = True Then
        Rows("10:10").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Rows("10:10").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

The code works perfectly.
Furthermore, if the value of cell C84 is not used elsewhere, the same can be obtained without using LinkedCell:

```
Sub CheckBox1_Click()

    Rows("10:10").EntireRow.Hidden = Not CheckBox1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

For it to unhide c84 value should be false as long as it is true it will be hidden only